# How to add array of integer field in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to add an array of integer fields in my model

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    day_of_the_week = ?? ( array of integer )
```

I tried with

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    day_of_the_week = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and in the serializer add ListField

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    day_of_the_week = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta():
        model = Schedule
        fields = "__all__"
```

but this one is not working can anyone suggest me how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    day_of_the_week = models.JSONField(default=list)

class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    day_of_the_week = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.IntegerField(),
    )

    class Meta():
        model = Schedule
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work with one small modification:

```
models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=100)
```

Comment: what is int_list_validator here?